# Scission of carbon dioxide bonds using electric arc

Tags: heat

I've done my research on this so I've seen the questions asking about the same premise without using plants.

Basically, this is a thought experiment I came up with. Whether or not I perform it depends on the feasibility. This is the reaction I'm thinking of:

$$
\ce{CO_2 \rightarrow C + O_2}
$$

From [NIST](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C124389&Units=SI&Mask=1) the formation energy of carbon dioxide back into carbon and oxygen is given as -393.52 kJ/mol.

The basic premise I was thinking of was that $\ce{CO_2}$ could be pressurized in a chamber with electrodes striking an arc, most likely from an HF driver source. The energy imparted to the carbon dioxide could be used to provide the dissociation energy to break the carbon-oxygen bonds.

If the electrodes were designed with sufficient voltage in mind to break the dielectric constant of the gas, a few rudimentary numbers suggest that even at 5% efficiency, a sustained power input of 1kW would break the bond of 1 mol of $\ce{CO_2}$ in about 2 hours.

My concerns with the feasibility of such a process are:

- Would it work? (i.e. would using an electric arc be a viable way to perform the bond decomposition? I'm not looking for an *industrially viable* process, just something that could produce a small end result.)
- Would I have to worry about the carbon and oxygen re-forming? Obviously, this would render moot the entire experiment. I know that $\ce{CO_2}$ decomposition doesn't appear to be an equilibrium process, but it's still a point of concern.
- If indeed it would work, how would the carbon likely present itself? I was thinking that if it sputtered itself against the vessel, the vessel could be weighed to determine the amount of carbon formed (and therefore the reaction efficiency, once the energy input was quantified).

Comment: Is this assuming that you have pure $\ce{CO2}$?

Comment: @ringo Exactly. Filled from a supply cylinder.

Comment: You will have varying amounts of carbon monoxide and ozone also likely being formed.  I think back-reaction to re-form CO2 would severely limit the attainable conversion, unless you can remove the C or the O2 continually to favor the equilibrium in the direction you want.

Comment: @CurtF. Could molecular sieves be used to remove oxygen continually from the vessel while maintaining pressure on the reactants?

Comment: Actually, it appears that due to the bond length similarities any sieve allowing diatomic oxygen would also most likely admit carbon monoxide.

Comment: Don't forget that $\ce{C + CO2 <=> 2 CO}$ is shifted to the right side with increasing temperature.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha If I were to perform this, I'd be attempting to maintain it as low a temperature as possible (that is, as close to 298K). Or are you referring to the arc conditions being the primary area where this equilibrium shift would occur?

Comment: @ecfedele The latter.